# How can I add badges/shields to github repos?

Tags: github, markdown, bintray, shields.io

I see sites like [shields.io](http://shields.io/) or similar and they have these clips of markdown to show badges...but if I cut 'n paste these it's just the demo value.  How can I make it "real".

For example [Bintray](http://www.bintray.com) has their own "Latest Version Badge" markdown that works fine.  I think the "shields" sites are trying to standardize the look 'n feel of these badges and they claim Bintray is one of their supported services.

How can I actually use their nice badge and pull my version data from Bintray?

Comment: Can you include some of the markdown that you've tried in your question?

Comment: This is (working) bintray tag: ```[ ![Download](https://api.bintray.com/packages/blocke/releases/scalajack/images/download.svg) ](https://bintray.com/blocke/releases/scalajack/_latestVersion)```.

Comment: This is what I'm trying (cut 'n paste from shields.io): ```[![Bintray](https://img.shields.io/bintray/v/asciidoctor/maven/asciidoctorj.svg?maxAge=2592000)](https://bintray.com/blocke/releases/scalajack)```.  I know something important is missing--just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A Bintray shield would look somthing like this:

```
[![Bintray](https://img.shields.io/bintray/v/asciidoctor/maven/asciidoctorj.svg?maxAge=2592000)](https://bintray.com/asciidoctor/maven/asciidoctorj)
```

There are two URIs in the shield the first is for the image and the second is for navigation upon clicking the image. Both URIs include `asciidoctor/maven/asciidoctorj` - a Bintray repository. If you replace both occurrences of `asciidoctor/maven/asciidoctorj` with your repository, you should have a working shield:

```
[![Bintray](https://img.shields.io/bintray/v/blocke/releases/scalajack.svg?maxAge=3600)](https://bintray.com/blocke/releases/scalajack)
```

[image: Bintray]

Comment: Be aware that by specifying `maxAge=2592000` the HTTP cache lifetime will be set to 30 days. You might want to use a smaller value.